# Google Assistant - How to re-prompt if the input is invalid?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am using Google Assistant with Node.js where I ask the user for check-in date and check-out date. 
If the check-out date is later than the check-in date then I want to add a re-prompt so that the user can tell a valid date. Is there a way to force a re-prompt from the code?

The code snippet is below:

```
    app.intent('myIntent', conv => {
        // validation
        const checkInDateString = conv.parameters[CHECK_IN_ARGUMENT];
        const checkOutDateString = conv.parameters[CHECK_OUT_ARGUMENT];

        var checkInDate = new Date(checkInDateString);
        var checkOutDate = new Date(checkOutDateString);

        console.log("Check-in date is: " + checkInDate.getTime());
        console.log("Check-out date is: " + checkOutDate.getTime());
        if (checkInDate.getTime() > checkOutDate.getTime())
        {
            conv.close('Pick a check-out date that is later than the check-in date!');
            console.error('The check-in date must be before the check-out date!');
        }
        else
        {
            // save to db.
        }
});
```

I don't want to close the conversation, but rather to do a re-prompt for the last question.

This is the first attempt after the check-out date failed.
[image]

and this is the second attempt:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a re-prompt after checking the date, you need to handle the parameters/slots in the NodeJS code by enabling "`Enable webhook call for slot filling`" at the bottom of the "add intent".

With this, for every parameter required, the webhook NodeJS code will be called and you can check the validity of the parameters.

The important point will be the re-prompt. When you want to re-prompt for correct parameter, you need to set the context programmatically. The issue will be that while collecting slots, dynamic context is generated by the Dialogflow for individual parameters.
You need to identify the context associated with your date parameter and if re-prompt, set that context with lifespan 2 so as to collect the parameter again.

A better way would be to have a separate individual intent for all the parameters that you want to validate. This way you will not have to identify the dynamic context and you can play with your own context while re-prompting.
**Update** - using second approach

- Identify the slots that require validation.
- Remove them from the current intent.
- Create separate intents for each slot that require validation.
- Enable webhook for these intents (not for the slot as you are collecting only one).
- In the webhook, if the validation fails, set the output context same as the input so as to trigger the same intent.
- Respond back with re-prompt response.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find a proper sample to deal with that? The  Prebuilt agents from Dialogflow don't seem to treat such a case.

Comment: Will try and update my answer for my second suggestion.

Comment: Updated my answer for better understanding

Comment: I have managed to set the context using this line:
conv.contexts.set('checkin_date',1);

However, I could also write:
conv.contexts.output.set('checkin_date',1);

but don't know what's the best practice around this. Which one would you use?

Comment: conv.contexts.set(checkin_date, 1);

Comment: I know that answer is old. Does someone was able to use the second aproach? For the intents that get the param value, do I need to add this parameter on this intent, mark it required and enable webhook for slot filling?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `conv.ask()` instead of `conv.close()`. Using `ask()` will send the message in the same way *but will expect the user to respond*. As the name might suggest, `close()` does close the microphone and end the conversation.

Comment: I tried that and it asked me to provide another date 3 times in a row. Even if I provided a correct date it closed the conversation. I only need to do a re-prompt, take the correct value and continue the conversation.

Comment: Is it calling your function each of those three times? Your function doesn't show it, but would it continue the conversation if it had valid data? Can you update your question to show the Intent you think should be called, and possibly screen shots of the simulator, and the request and response tabs in it, showing what its doing when it reprompts?

Comment: I have updated the code. if the data is valid it should continue and save the data to db. I don't have any function being called, it's just the intent as it is described above.

Comment: What do the Intents look like in the Dialogflow intent builder screen?

Comment: I have added more screenshots with the DialogFlow intents that I've used. I have also created a fallback intent which asks the check-out date for 3 times before it closes the conversation. Do I need to create a function inside index.js to handle the fallback or what is the best practice in this case? 

I don't need just to force the user to type a date, I need to force him to put a date that is later than the check-in date.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally here for simplicity, consider using [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts), as those accomplish some persistence of state.

In your example, the action can fail correctly (as it should), but also save the check-in date so the next call can run correctly with both dates. The "7th March 2018" request can also trigger the same action, but read the check-in date already saved and function correctly.